# How to count the number of numbers below N having only one or two prime factors?

Tags: c++, counter, factors

There are how many numbers below n having only one or two prime factors?? Like below 100 there are 91 numbers which have only one or two prime factors excluding 9 (some of them are 60, 66, 78, 90).

I'd like to do this in C++.

Comment: Course assignment? :)

Comment: If you don't find solving this yourself remotely challenging then change course.

Comment: my tip: do not factorize all n numbers, but just count all numbers that you can construct as product of two prime numbers p1 and p2 with p1*p2 <= n

Comment: @tobi303, IIUC you would need those plus the number of primes <n, which is nearly as hard as factorizing all numbers less than n.  If you want more program complexity for less execution time (which I doubt the OP wants) then focus on the excluded numbers `(p1*p2*x)<n` where p1<p2 and x has a prime factors larger than p2.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a "write this code for me" style question.

Comment: @JSF for some reason i was assuming that a list prime numbers is available beforehand. Practically it boils down to: Find all prime numbers < n (and identifying the numbers with two factors requires only minor modification to the sieve)

Answer (score -3):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    long long num, i, k, counter, b = 0, a, flag;
    cout << "Enter Number" << endl;
    cin >> num;
    counter = 0;
    for (a = 2; a <= num; a++)
    {
        counter = 0;
        i = 2;
        for (i = 2; i <= a; i++)
        {
            flag = 0;
            k = 2;
            if (a%i == 0) {
                while (k <= i - 1) {
                    if (i%k == 0) {
                        flag = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                    k++;
                }
                if (flag == 0)
                {
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }
        if (counter <= 2)
        {
            b++;
        }
    }
    cout << "Total Number Which Have One Or Two Prime Factor are :: " << b << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Rubbish. This is O(nn). There are better ways. See question comments for one of them.

Comment: Christ this code is horrible. How does this help anyone?

Comment: I tend to recommend that questions as off-topic as this one are not attempted, since it is likely to result in answers getting downvotes too. Also, it is worth improving the indentation here.